why I got database is locked error insted of inserting the token into the database
in the next code I'm trying to store the token into the database along with the username but it always give this error :
authenticating... 
2024-05-10 01:41:58,350 - INFO - authenticating locally... 
2024-05-10 01:42:03,663 - ERROR - An unexpected error occurred: database is locked 
2024-05-10 01:42:03,663 - INFO - Database connection closed. 
2024-05-10 01:42:03,663 - INFO - User admin authenticated successfully.

the user is authenticated but the token is not been stored in the table.
I don't know why it is making this I tried everything I though about but it is not working.
if you can help me with this I'll be grateful.
the code:
Authenticator.py:

import sqlite3, secrets, logging

# to provide password hashing utilites
from passlib.hash import argon2
from datahandler import checkInternet

from AddToken import add_token_to_database

# Configures the logging system to display all logs with a severity level of INFO or higher.
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
)
# Creates a logger with the name ‘authenticator’for logging messages within this module.
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class DatabaseManager:
    def __init__(self, db_path):
        # Establishes a connection to the SQLite database at the specified path.
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        # Creates a cursor object to execute SQL commands.
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def close(self):
        # Closes the SQLite database connection.
        self.conn.close()


class Authenticator:
    def __init__(self, db_manager):
        self.db_manager = db_manager

    async def authenticate_online(self, username, password):
        # Placeholder for online authentication logic
        return False, None

    def authenticate_locally(self, username, password):
        logger.info("authenticating locally...")
        try:
            self.db_manager.cursor.execute(
                "SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = ?", (username,)
            )
            result = self.db_manager.cursor.fetchone()

            if result is None:
                logger.error(f"No user found with the username: {username}")
                return False, None

            hashed_password = result[0]
            if hashed_password and argon2.verify(password, hashed_password):
                token = create_session_token()
                add_token_to_database(username, token)
                logger.info(f"User {username} authenticated successfully.")
                return True, token
            else:
                logger.error(f"Password verification failed for user: {username}")
                return False, None
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            logger.error(f"SQLite error during local authentication: {e}")
            return False, None
        except ValueError as e:
            logger.error(f"Malformed Argon2 hash, or other library error: {e}")
            return False, None

    async def authenticate(self, username, password):
        print("authenticating...")
        if checkInternet("www.google.com", 3):
            # online authentication
            success, token = await self.authenticate_online(username, password)
        else:
            # offline authentication
            success, token = self.authenticate_locally(username, password)
            if success:
                # Ensures that a valid token is returned, either a new one or an existing valid session token.
                token = token or self.get_valid_session_token(username)
        return success, token

    # retrieves a valid session token for the user if it exists.
    def get_valid_session_token(self, username):
        self.db_manager.cursor.execute(
            "SELECT Token FROM Sessions WHERE Username = ?", (username,)
        )
        result = self.db_manager.cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            return result[0]
        return None


# function to generate a secure session token using the secrets module
def create_session_token():
    return secrets.token_urlsafe(16)

AddToken.py:

import sqlite3, logging


logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def add_token_to_database(username, token, db_path="DB.db"):
    try:
        with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                """
                INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Sessions (Username, Token) VALUES (?, ?)
                """,
                (username, token),
            )
            conn.commit()
            logger.info("Session token inserted/updated successfully for user: %s", username)
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        logger.error(f"Integrity error when adding token: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        logger.info("Database connection closed.")


loginHandler.py:
import json, logging
from Authenticator import DatabaseManager, Authenticator


db_path = "./DB.db"
db_manager = DatabaseManager(db_path)
authenticator = Authenticator(db_manager)

# Initialize logger
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# An asynchronous function that listens for login requests over a WebSocket connection
# and It decodes the JSON message, extracts the username and password, and attempts to authenticate the user
# If authentication is successful, it sends back a JSON response with a success flag and a session token.
async def handle_login(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        try:
            data = json.loads(message)
            if data.get("action") == "login":
                username = data["username"]
                password = data["password"]
                authenticated, token = await authenticator.authenticate(
                    username, password
                )
                if authenticated:
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps({"success": True, "token": token}))
                else:
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps({"success": False}))
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            await websocket.send(
                json.dumps({"success": False, "error": "Invalid JSON"})
            )
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Login handling error: %s", e)
            await websocket.send(
                json.dumps({"success": False, "error": "Internal server error"})
            )

I expeted the the token to be stored in the database after every verifying of the user

SQLite allows concurrent connections for reading, but only a single process can write to the database at any given time. You're seeing the error on a write operation, so it seems likely that there's another program running with a connection to the database.

I checked the code in the module that contains an INSERT query, and it is not running or executed at that point is there any to avoid that @Grismar

Since you want to change the database, avoiding INSERT is not the answer - whatever operation you use to change the database will case the same error. Like I said, your authentication step only requires read operations, but storing the token will require a write operation. Check if you have any other software running that may have the database open. Check if the database is on storage that allows your script to write to files. Perhaps ensure your script can run outside an editor or IDE and see if the same problem occurs.
